# How can I stream videos using JW Player?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I currently have JW Player setup so that it's first option is HTML5, the fallback is FLV then fallback to that is Download.

Only the HTML5 route seems to stream the videos, but I need it to stream the videos in the flash route too.

Any ideas what additional parameters I need to use?

The current setup is as follows:

```
jwplayer('the_video_container').setup({
            'id': 'playerID',
            'width': '654',
            'height': '410',
            'file': '/video/keyword_vid_1.mp4',
            'autostart': 'true',
            'controlbar': 'none',
            'screencolor': 'FFFFFF',
            'repeat': 'always',
            'modes': [
                {type: 'html5'},
                {type: 'flash', src: '/js/jwplayer/player.swf'},
                {type: 'download'}
            ]
        });
```

Comment: When you say 'stream' do you actually mean *stream* or do you mean 'progressive download'?

Comment: @daniel0mullins, by "stream" I mean the user doesn't have to wait for the whole mp4 to download before the video starts playing..

Comment: Progressive download will do that for you, or at least it should if your video files are hinted correctly. What are you using to encode? And I *think* you may have your setup variables out of whack. I'm pretty sure `src` there in `modes` for `flash` is an alternate version of `file`. I think what you want is to set the `flashplayer` variable.

Comment: @daniel0mullins, the mp4 files are H.264, and the "code" is as above and does the job for everything else, just doesnt seem to be "progressive" when it comes to the non-html5 routes. What do I need to change to get it to work?

Comment: You should set the `flashplayer` attribute. See answer below.

Comment: Right, the mp4 files are using the H.264 codec, but what *program* are you using to encode? Adobe Media Encoder? Sorenson Squeeze? Something else?

Comment: Right, it seems that it's because the moov atom header information is at the end of the file, so it needs to be brought to the front, I've been able to do this with 1 of 3 videos, so once I've completed the move of moov :P then I will confirm that it worked as the solution or not!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up your JW Player as follows:

```
jwplayer('the_video_container').setup({
        'id': 'playerID',
        'flashplayer':'/js/jwplayer/player.swf',
        'width': '654',
        'height': '410',
        'file': '/video/keyword_vid_1.mp4',
        'autostart': 'true',
        'controlbar': 'none',
        'screencolor': 'FFFFFF',
        'repeat': 'always',
        'modes': [
            {type: 'html5'},
            {type: 'flash'},
            {type: 'download'}
        ]
    });
```

And remember, you may want to include additional `src` attributes in the `html5` block for those browser that don't support mp4 in html5 playback.